# Load dynamic layout in blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

**What I am trying?**

I am trying to load a layout file in blade which has dynamic path due to language difference.

**I have a class below in Laravel 7.**

```
namespace App\Architecture\Blades;

class BladesList {
    const layout = "themes.default.en.layouts.layout";
}
```

Below is the code present in blade

```
@extends('{!!\App\Architecture\Blades\BladesList::layout !!}')
```

**Error Message**

```
No hint path defined for [{!!\App\Architecture\Blades\BladesList].
```

Comment: you are in a blade directive, its php   `@extends(\App\Architecture\Blades\BladesList::layout)`

Answer (score 2):

you have to remove `{{!!  !!}}` wrap to be like:

```
@extends(\App\Architecture\Blades\BladesList::layout)
```